# Getting array count with PHP, inserting count in HTML and fetching with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

With PHP I'm catching the amount of rows that got returned from the query.

```
$resultRowsCount = count($resultRows);
```

I'm inserting this to HTML.

```
<section class="main-results" value="<?php print $resultRowsCount ?>"> </section>
```

So that JavaScript can get that value.

```
let resultAmount = document.getElementsByClassName("main-results").value ;
```

But somehow it's giving me 'undefined' when I try to log `resultAmount`

I tried to change the type but that didnt work.

```
settype($resultRowsCount,'string');
settype($resultRowsCount,'integer');
```

This is what I get in the dev tool
[image]

Comment: Maybe read the documentation [Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). That function doesn't return an element. So it's return doesn't have a "value" property. Hence ... `undefined`

Comment: `document.getElements` ...note the plural: "Element**s**" - it doesn't return a single element, but a _collection_ of elements. So clearly the returned object, being a collection, will not have a value. You need to find the specific element within the collection which you are interested in, and get its value. (if you know there will definitely be only one element returned, then it's easy, of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `getElementsByClassName()` method returns an array of matching elements, so you want to get the first one with index=0:

`let resultAmount = document.getElementsByClassName('main-results')[0]`

And you want the HTML attribute of `value` so you could use something like:

`let resultAmount = document.getElementsByClassName('main-results')[0].getAttribute('value')`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidgamero/95sacmkf/6/)

Answer (score 2):

2 issues with your 1, one, your use getElementsByClassName and you expect to get only 1 element, while you actually get an array of elements.

As for the second one, you better use data-* attributes, which is just what you need for your usage.

May that work for you?

```
<section class="main-results" id="results-<?= $resultRowsCount ?>" data-count="<?= $resultRowsCount ?>"> </section>

<script>
    var resultElement = document.getElementById("results-<?= $resultRowsCount ?>");
    // 'Getting' data-attributes using getAttribute
    var dataCount = resultElement .getAttribute('data-count'); // fruitCount = '12'
    // 'Setting' data-attributes using setAttribute
    resultElement.setAttribute('data-count', 'other-value');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation! Part of the problem was indeed that multiple results are being returned

Answer (score 2):

`value` is not a standard attribute of `<section>` elements. The `.value` property only works with input elements and their components.

If you want a custom attribute, you should use `data-value`.

Also since `getElementsByClassName()` returns a NodeList, you need to index it. If there's just one element like this, perhaps you should use an ID instead of class.

```
<section class="main-results" data-value="<?php print $resultRowsCount ?>"> </section>
```

and then you access it using the `dataset` property.

```
let resultAmount = document.getElementsByClassName("main-results")[0].dataset.value ;
```

Comment: Worked with .getAttribute('value') instead of .dataset.value . Indeed forgot that I'm getting multiple results..

Comment: Yes, that will work, but it's still a bad idea to create custom attributes. That's what `dataset` is for.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you don't need to use html to give javascript the value:

Option 1 (which I think might not work due to so many people avoiding that):

```
<script>
let resultAmount = <?php echo $resultRowsCount?>;
//code ...
</script>
```

You'll need to make sure `$resultRowsCount` is a number value.

Option 2:

```
<?php
  echo "<script>let resultAmount = $resultRowsCount</script>";
?>
```

Put `''` around `$resultRowsCount` if it's a string.
Note: the double quotations are to escape variables.

Please notify if any mistakes are found.